# How to compare the same variable using models with different covariates?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model

I have measures from an epigenetic variable from two different groups (Treatment and control) measured in two different tissues. I have identified differences for this epigenetic variables between Treatment and control groups (Group) in each tissue separately, splitting my data into two subsets (one for each tissue) using the following models in R:

`model_tissue_1   <- lm(Epigenetic_variable ~ Group + Age + Sex + Cell_proportion_1 + Cell_proportion_2 + Cell_proportion_3 + Cell_proportion_4, data = my_data_tissue_1)`

`model_tissue_2   <- lm(Epigenetic_variable ~ Group + Age + Sex + **Cell_proportion_1 + Cell_proportion_2 + Cell_proportion_3 + Cell_proportion_4 + Cell_proportion_5 + Cell_proportion_6** + pH, data = my_data_tissue_2)`

Please note that each model includes different cell proportions as covariates, according to the studied tissue. Also, model_tissue_2 includes an additional covariate that was not measured in the other tissue (pH).

Now, I would like to evaluate cross-tissue differences for the Epigenetic_variable among the groups, i.e., to identify Epigenetic variable differences between tissue_1 and tissue_2 for individuals in the Control group, as well as in the Treatment group, if possible considering all the covariates from each model. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why did you split the data rather than include tissue as a covariate ?

Comment: Because I wanted to explore the differences on Epigenetic_variable in each tissue and to consider the different cell proportions from each tissue, including them as covariates.

Comment: That doesn't tell me that you should split the data. Unless I am missing something, splitting the data means you can't answer your research question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will merge my data and make new groups considering both the experimental group and tissue, i.e., control_tissue_1, control_tissue_2, treatment_tissue1 and treatment_tissue_2 and include the cell proportions and other variables from both tissues as covariates. Then, I will performe comparisons among the groups. Do you think that this approach will be ok?

Comment: Yes, that would be my advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% clear about this but my understanding is that a dataset has been split by tissue type. A model has been fitted on each subset, using largely the same variables in each model (at least one variable is constant/absent for one tissue type).

The research question centres on a comparison of the estimates for some of the variables between the two models.

If I have understood this correctly, then I don't think the estimates can be compared in a meaningful way. The way I would approach this is to work with the whole dataset and include a variable to identify the tissue type. This may need to be interacted with other variables to answer the research question.

Comment: Yes, the dataset was split by tissue type into two subset, and a model was fitted for each subset with same variables in each model. Also, I included specific covariates for each model that are not present in the model (cell proportion from each tissue and pH). Thanks for your recommendation, I will test interactions among the variables in a model fitted for the whole dataset (both tissues).

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, and if not please let us know why.